Program for obtaining the distance between protein and bound tRNA
I would like to find the smallest distance between each residue in an enzyme and the DNA. Is there software for obtaining that? Say I have this bound enzyme, I would ultimately like to create a table that has each residue position in the enzyme and the shortest distance to the RNA:

Position  Residue   ShortestDistanceToRNA
7         GLU         Xangstroms

etc.
Any suggestions?

+1. Welcome to our community.

Thank you very much @Camps!!!

You can use VMD to do this. You can paste this code in the tkconsole in the VMD. That outputs a data file named minimum_distance_data.dat. On the PDB you shared, it took around 2 minutes, but the code can be heavily optimized further for larger complexes.
mol load pdb 5e6m.pdb
set protein_sel [atomselect top "protein"]
set dna_sel [atomselect top "not protein"]
set indices_dna_sel [$dna_sel get index]
set residues [lsort -u -integer [$protein_sel get resid]]
set fp [open "minimum_distance_data.dat" w+]

foreach residue $residues {
  set residue_sel [atomselect top "residue $residue"]
  set resname [lsort -u [$residue_sel get resname]]
  set residue_sel_center [measure center $residue_sel]
  set all_distances {}
  foreach index $indices_dna_sel {
    set index_sel [atomselect top "index $index"]
    set index_sel_coords [lindex [$index_sel get {x y z}] 0]
    set distance [vecdist $residue_sel_center $index_sel_coords]
    lappend all_distances $distance
    $index_sel delete
  }
  set min_dist [lindex [lsort -real $all_distances] 0]
  puts $fp "$residue $resname $min_dist"
  $residue_sel delete
}
close $fp

minimum_distance.dat

This is excellent. Thank you!!!

@ramiro If you find the answer useful, can you upvote and accept it?

Absolutely, forgot. Thank you again very much @Vasista
